# Aerospike Python Client. UDF module to count records. Cannot register module

Tags: python, client, user-defined-functions, aerospike, nosql

I am currently implementing the Aerospike Python Client in order to benchmark it along with our Redis implementation, to see which is faster and/or more stable.

I'm still on baby steps, currently Unit-Testing basic functionality, for example  if I correctly add records in my Set. For that reason, I want to create a function to count them.

I saw in Aerospike's [Documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/usage/udf/apply.html), that :

> "to perform an aggregation on query, you first need to register a UDF
>   with the database".

It seems that this is the suggested way that aggregations, counting and other custom functionality should be run in Aerospike.

Therefore, to count the records in a set I have, I created the following module:

```
# "counter.lua"

function count(s)
    return s : map(function() return 1 end) : reduce (function(a,b) return a+b end)
end
```

I'm trying to use aerospike python client's function to register a UDF(User Defined Function) module:

> udf_put(filename, udf_type, policy)

My code is as follows:

```
# aerospike_client.py:

# "udf_put" parameters
policy = {'timeout': 1000}
lua_module = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "counter.lua") #same folder
udf_type = aerospike.UDF_TYPE_LUA # equals to "0", which is for "Lua"

self.client.udf_put(lua_module, udf_type, policy) # Exception is thrown here

query = self.client.query(self.aero_namespace, self.aero_set)
query.select()
result = query.apply('counter', 'count')
```

an exception is thrown:

> exceptions.Exception: (-2L, 'Filename should be a string', 'src/main/client/udf.c', 82)

1. Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong?
2. Is there a way to "debug" it without compiling C code?
3. Is there any other suggested way to count the records in my set? Or I'm fine with the Lua module?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not seeing that exception, but I am seeing a bug with udf_put where the module is registered but the python process hangs. I can see the module appear on the server using AQL's `show modules`.

I [opened a bug](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues/49) with the Python client's repo on Github, [aerospike/aerospike-client-python](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/i).

There's a best practices document regarding UDF development here: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/best_practices.html

In general using the stream-UDF to aggregate the records through the count function is the correct way to go about it. There are examples [here](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/php/usage/udf/aggregate.html#the-aggregation-stream-udf) and [here](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/counting-distinct-unique/260).

Comment: That big is fixed with the latest release. Did you have a chance to verify?

Comment: Sorry did not have chance to verify yet, will do when it's possible! Thanks